# Exclude contained php-code in javascript in minifier.org

Tags: javascript, php, minify

I'm using https://www.minifier.org/ (https://github.com/matthiasmullie/minify/) to minify my javascript prior to uploading it on the live-server. This works fine.

Now I need to minify a file which contains mixed JavaScript- and PHP-Code (the PHP-Code is echoing Javascript-Code dynamically). My problem is that minifier.org of course thinks the PHP-Code is JavaScript and minifies it, resulting in PHP-errors. Is there a way to tell the Minifier to just exclude everything between ?

Comment: why are you using your server to generate client-side code?

Comment: In short, you are doing it wrong.  Instead of using php to render your javascript, separate your frontend and backend concerns by passing data to your javascript.  Javascript needs a lot of things, but another transpiler is not one of them.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Imagin you have one webserver for 3 different domains and just want to put different texts for each page into the javascript using the same code-basis without generating 3 different javascript and without maintaning the texts inside the PHP AND Javascript. Of course you could do this with ajax and load the data from the server, but this is more time-consuming than just "printing" it into the javascript.

Comment: @Werner imagine one webserver for 12 :) I still just do the JS individually per site instead of server-generating the code. It's much better and cleaner, sometimes the longer path is the right one